# Why can't I return NULL from a const String& method?

Tags: c++, constants

I have the following method declaration:
`const String& MyClass::GetAspect(const String& strKey) const`

In this method, we've decided to do a null-pointer check before doing some stuff; if the pointer inside this method is `null`, we want to just return `null`.

However, I get the following error:

```
myclass.cpp(222) : error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const String &'
        Reason: cannot convert from 'int' to 'const String'
        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Could someone help me understand this? Is there some const-correctness concept I don't fully understand here?

Comment: References cannot be NULL

Comment: Use assertions to signal precondition violations, use exceptions to signal runtime errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NULL` is not an object of type `const String`, so of course you can't return it when a reference to `const String` is expected. In fact, one of the major advantages of references is that they can't (ever) be `NULL`.

Re-define the function to return `const String *`, or return an empty `String`.

Comment: Or, throw an exception.

Comment: Note that you cannot just `return "";` because the caller would end up with a dangling reference.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is a pointer (or technically, the integer value zero, which can be converted to/from a pointer, `nullptr` is a pointer with the value zero).

A `std::string&` is not a pointer (or an integer), so you can't use `NULL` for it. You could return `""` or `"Unknown"` or something like that.

Comment: Note that you cannot just `return "";` because the caller would end up with a dangling reference.

Comment: I'd rather `return CString();`, which will also yield an empty string.